# Smart diagram in Mathematica

Tags: graphics

I am wondering if I can get a smart diagram in Mathematica like the following one obtained with LaTeX

[image]

found here

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pdca-cycle/

and modified here

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487891/modifying-the-colors-of-arcarrow

I could do it from scratch. I just want to find out if there are any built-in functionalities for such purposes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a kind of `SectorChart`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get most of the way there with just `PieChart`:

```
PieChart[{{
   Labeled[1, 
    Style["PDCA\nCycle", Large, 
     TextAlignment -> Center], {{0, 0}, {.4, .5}}]
   }, Labeled[1, Style[#, Larger]] & /@ {"Plan", "Do", "Check", 
    "Act"}}]
```

[image]